# How to calculate the total value in the json in Python

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I have a json file in which I need to calculate the total duration which is the sum of the "duration" in python.

The values inside the data are dynamic and we don't know the expected value only the structure is same.

```
{
  "data": {
    "9": {
      "mp_e_b": {
        "english": {
          "english_literature": {
            "video_lessons": {
              "The Fun They Had": {
                "-NNH9_LnN_RBLjxN3lKN": {
                  "class_name": "9",
                  "duration": "28",
                  "subject_name": "English Literature"
                 },
                "-NNH9jblawQprJ9-ZFmw": {
                  "class_name": "9",
                  "duration": "25",
                  "subject_name": "English Literature"
                 }
              }
            }
          },
          "hindi_grammar": {
            "video_lessons": {
              "हिंदी भाषा": {
                "-NNHA6axQjjM991cPvW_": {
                  "class_name": "9",
                  "duration": "76",
                  "subject_name": "हिन्दी व्याकरण"
                 }
              }
            }
          },
          "history": {
            "video_lessons": {
              "The French Revolution": {
                "-NNHAM0yNF4YcoQSTBRf": {
                  "class_name": "9",
                  "duration": "56",
                  "subject_name": "History"
                  }
              }
            }
          },
          "science": {
            "video_lessons": {
              "Matter in Our Surroundings": {
                "-NNHAC_cPxJTZ5iQYj3k": {
                  "class_name": "9",
                  "duration": "5",
                  "subject_name": "Science"
                  },
                "-NNHAFNjXkIJjLMuWmQU": {
                  "class_name": "9",
                  "duration": "3",
                  "subject_name": "Science"
                  }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "hindi": {
          "computers": {
            "video_lessons": {
              "जावास्क्रिप्ट के प्रयोग से क्लाइंट की ओर से स्क्रिप्टिंग": {
                "-NNHAnYUZNVek70Amlbb": {
                  "class_name": "9",
                  "duration": "20",
                  "subject_name": "Computers"
                  }
              }
            }
          },
          "english_literature": {
            "video_lessons": {
              "The Fun They Had": {
                "-NO5EMyVA3PgaxoeYzbQ": {
                  "class_name": "9",
                  "duration": "49",
                  "subject_name": "English Literature"
                 }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried solving this with applying nested for loop but couldn't find another way to do it or do it faster.

```
def reports_data():
    a = input("Enter the UID for the total reports: ")
    # userclass = input("Enter which class data you want to see or write 'all': ")
    total_time = []
    users = db.child("reports").child("app_reports").child(a).child("data").get()
    for i in users.each():
        # user_class = (i.key())
        var_class = (i.val()) #json of the class is being stored in the var variable
        for x, y in var_class.items():
                var_board = (y) #json of the board is being stored in the var variable
                for q, w in var_board.items():
                    var_lang = (w) #json of the language is being stored in the var variable
                    for e, r in var_lang.items():
                        var_subject = (r) #json of the subject is being stored in the var variable
                        for t, s in var_subject.items():
                            var_mode = (s) #json of the subject is being stored in the var variable
                            for u, o in var_mode.items():
                                var_chap = (o) #json of the type is being stored in the var variable
                                for a, p in var_chap.items():
                                    var_mode = (p) #json of the mode is being stored in the var variable
                                    for d, f in var_mode.items():
                                    #  outfile.write(f) #json of the perticular item watched is being stored in the var variable                                                
                                        if d == 'duration':
                                            total_time.append(f)
    total = sum(int(time) for time in total_time)
    print("Total time:", total,"sec")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that doing it in nested for loop is already sufficiently fast.
However, if you don't mind being a little bit slower, and are seeking for a succinct piece of code, here's my approach, in which the dictionary is traversed recursively using stack, adding up all values with keys named "duration":

```py
with open('file.json') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

total = 0
stack = [data]
while stack:
    top = stack.pop()
    for key, value in top.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            stack.append(value)
        elif key == 'duration':
            try:
                total += int(value)
            except ValueError:
                pass

print(total)
```

Timing:

```
      my code: 3.551e-05 sec (shorter code)
Bitrey's code: 9.897e-06 sec (faster)
```

Or else, if you wish to only evaluate "duration" in certain depths of the json, here's my solution:

```py
expected_depths = [8]  # or whatever you'd like

with open('file.json') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

total = 0
stack = [(0, data)]
while stack:
    d, top = stack.pop()
    for key, value in top.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            stack.append((d + 1, value))
        # you may also change `d in expected_depths` to other
        # conditions, e.g., `d > ...`
        elif key == 'duration' and d in expected_depths:
            try:
                total += int(value)
            except ValueError:
                pass

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python implementation:

```
import json

# load the JSON file into a Python dictionary
with open('file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# initialize a variable to store the sum of the durations
duration_sum = 0

# loop over the video lessons for each subject and language
for subject_class in data['data']:
    for board in data['data'][subject_class]:
        for language in data['data'][subject_class][board]:
            for subject in data['data'][subject_class][board][language]:
                for video_lesson in data['data'][subject_class][board][
                        language][subject]['video_lessons']:
                    # loop over each video lesson's duration and add it to the sum
                    for video_id in data['data'][subject_class][board][
                            language][subject]['video_lessons'][video_lesson]:
                        duration_sum += int(
                            data['data'][subject_class][board][language]
                            [subject]['video_lessons'][video_lesson][video_id]
                            ['duration'])

# output the sum of the durations
print(duration_sum)
```

If you want to take it to the extreme, just for fun:

```
import json
data = json.load(open('file.json'))
print(sum(int(data['data'][subject_class][board][language][subject]['video_lessons'][video_lesson][video_id]['duration']) for subject_class in data['data'] for board in data['data'][subject_class] for language in data['data'][subject_class][board] for subject in data['data'][subject_class][board][language] for video_lesson in data['data'][subject_class][board][language][subject]['video_lessons'] for video_id in data['data'][subject_class][board][language][subject]['video_lessons'][video_lesson]))
```